# Do I really need to implement iterator in that case?

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I need some advice about usage of `Iterable<T>` in Java.

I have the following class:

```
public abstract class Validator implements Comparable<Validator>{
    public abstract boolean validate();
    public abstract int getPriority();

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Validator o) {
        return getPriority() > o.getPriority() ? -1 :
                getPriority() == o.getPriority() ? 0 : 
                    1;
    }
}
```

I need to create a class `ValidatorChain` as follows:

```
public class ValidatorChain{
    //Contains Collection<Validator>

    // and we can iterate over it with for-each loop in high-to-low priority order
}
```

Maybe I should just override some instant implementation of `Iterable<T>` instead of writing my own one from scratch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write it manually in a simple way by delegating to the collection's iterator:

```
public class ValidatorChain implements Iterable<Validator> {
  Collection<Validator> validators = ...;
  public Iterator<Validator> iterator() {
    return validators.iterator();
  }
}
```

If you need it sorted, you can either sort the `validators` collections or take a copy:

```
  public Iterator<Validator> iterator() {
    List<Validator> sorted = new ArrayList<> (validators);
    Collections.sort(sorted);
    return sorted.iterator();
  }
```

Or with Java 8:

```
 public Iterator<Validator> iterator() {
    return validators.stream().sorted().collect(toList()).iterator();
  }
```

Comment: avoiding sometimes dangerous inheritance +1

Comment: How can I respect the order?

Comment: validators.sort();, Natural sorting with Comparable sorts the collection as you expect

Comment: I meant the order with foreach loop

Comment: I want the user to iterate in high-to-low order with for-each loop

Comment: you have to sort the collection than you iterate

Comment: I got what you mean. But why don't we just use `SortedSet` or some and then return the iterator of the set?

Comment: @DmitryBundin it depends if you want to allow duplicates (elements with same priority). If that is allowed then TreeSet won't work.

Comment: `to list()` should be `Collectors.toList()`

Comment: @immibis yes or use a static import

Answer (score 3):

You can only extends your `ValidatorChain` with a collection:

```
public class ValidatorChain extends ArrayList<Validator>{
    //...
}
```

Now it is iterable, because of extending ArrayList which is iterable itself

Comment: Why extend arraylist if all you need is a for each loop? Composition in this case makes more sense than inheritance...

Comment: For only one for each loop I agree, but this approach will be useful in the future despite some bad thing it brings with. And a question was: "Do I really need to" @assylias